# Wordpress: how to use Wordpress post format with REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I'm building a blog for a mobile app have 2 post formats **standard** and **video** by using the WordPress function:

```php
add_theme_support(
    'post-formats',
    array(
        // 'aside',
        // 'image',
        'video',
        // 'quote',
        // 'link',
        // 'gallery',
        // 'audio',
    )
);
```

This functions ads the **formats widget** on the post and shows the **format** field on the REST API at `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`.

The issue is I can't filter posts by the format, I can't do the following for example `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?format=video`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to use this plugin [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-filter/) and the rest API point becomes:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[post_format]=post-format-xxx
```